# When using nowrap, how can I delete a line and stay in the same screen?

Tags: wrapping

I sometimes work with files that have longish (200+ characters) lines, and I've recently discovered the joy of `:nowrap` mode.  It's quite convenient.

However, when I'm scrolled over to the right by a few screen widths, and I use `dd` to delete a line, the screen jumps back to the leftmost position of the following line.

Is there a way to avoid this?  I'd prefer that the screen stay where it is, and the cursor just travel down one row.  (The following line is equally long.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can `set nostartofline` to get this.

It would also make it stay on the same column while using jumps like `gg` or `G`, `CTRL-F`, `L` etc.

See `:h startofline` for more details.

```
'startofline' 'sol' boolean (default on)
            global
    When "on" the commands listed below move the cursor to the first
    non-blank of the line.  When off the cursor is kept in the same column
    (if possible).  This applies to the commands: CTRL-D, CTRL-U, CTRL-B,
    CTRL-F, "G", "H", "M", "L", gg, and to the commands "d", "<<" and ">>"
    with a linewise operator, with "%" with a count and to buffer changing
    commands (CTRL-^, :bnext, :bNext, etc.).  Also for an Ex command that
    only has a line number, e.g., ":25" or ":+".
    In case of buffer changing commands the cursor is placed at the column
    where it was the last time the buffer was edited.
```